# How to implement multiple GP submodels in PYMC

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, gaussian-process, pymc

I'm hoping someone can give me some guidance on implementing 
Gaussian processes (GP) with PYMC. In particular, I'm not sure how to use
multiple GP submodels properly within a single pymc model.

More specifically, what I'd like to implement is a classifier for which the
input is a time-varying signal (an audio snippet, in this case). For concreteness,
the goal is to determine from the input signal whether or not a whale is
present (see the Kaggle whale detection competition). So, there are two
categories, 'whale' or 'no-whale', which I encode as 1, 0, respectively, and
model with a Bernoulli random variable.

On 'whale' trials, there is a whale call embedded somewhere in the audio signal.
On any given trial we don't know when the call starts or ends, but we assume that
the call is fairly stereotyped, and therefore varies little from trial to trial
(but on each 'whale' trial we observe a noisy version of it).

I'm trying to model the background (no-whale) signal using GP submodels which
share a common prior mean function and covariance function, and the 'whale' signal
using a single GP submodel with a different covariance function (and possibly different 
prior mean, but in what I've coded here all submodels are zero mean).

On 'whale' trials, the call is embedded into the background signal, starting
at 't_start' and lasting for 'call_dur' time units. 't_start' and 'call_dur' are
both random variables.

My question is whether or not I really need separate submodels for each no-whale
signal or whether I can use a single no-whale submodel and tell it to draw a new
realization for each trial. (see comments in code, below). The code below
runs very very slowly -- it seems to take a long time to instantiate each
GP submodel -- too slowly to be useful. Is there any way around this?

Thanks for any suggestions!

---- code follows ----

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import pymc as pm
import pymc.gp as pmgp

# for concreteness, here are the values
# passed in through the params object
#input_T = 4000
#params.t_start_mean = 0.25 * input_T
#params.t_start_var = 0.1 * input_T
#params.call_dur_mean = 0.4 * input_T
#params.call_dur_var = 0.05 * input_T
#params.n_fmesh = 25
#whale_prior = 0.5

def make_hbayes_model(params, whale_prior, sigs, obs_wtf=None):

    # The data in 'sigs' are a set of 1-dimensional signals (audio snippets) passed in as a
    # numpy array of size sig_N x sig_T, i.e., sig_N trials, each of duration sig_T
    # Trials can be one of two categories -- 'whale'(1), or 'no-whale'(0).
    # On 'whale' trials, there is a whale call
    # embedded somewhere in the audio snippet, on 'no-whale' trials there is not.
    # When training the model, the true categories are passed in in 'obs_wtf',
    # i.e., whale true/false, 0 for no-whale, 1 for whale.
    sig_N, sig_T = np.shape(sigs)

    fmesh_nowhale = np.linspace(0, sig_T, params.n_fmesh) # fmesh for the no-whale GP
    # A guess at what fraction of the total snippet the embedded whale call lasts
    call_dur_frac = params.call_dur_mean / sig_T 
    # fmesh for 'whale' GP
    fmesh_whale = np.linspace(0, params.call_dur_mean, int(params.n_fmesh*call_dur_frac))

    if obs_wtf is None: # when predicting
        obs_wtf_flag = False
    else: # when training the model
        obs_wtf_flag = True

    # The random variable for generating the category (whale or no-whale)
    # 'whale_prior' is the known value (from the training data) of Pr(whale)
    # 'wtf' is, of course, observed when training, but is what we want to predict when, uh,
    # predicting
    wtf = pm.Bernoulli('wtf', p=whale_prior, value=obs_wtf, observed=obs_wtf_flag)
    # we need to know how many whales so we know into how many sound signals we need
    # to embed a whale call
    N_whales = np.sum(wtf.value)

    # On 'whale' trials, we know there is a whale call embedded, but we do not know exactly where
    # it starts or exactly how long it lasts. The full snippet is only 2 secs long, and the call is around
    # 1 sec long, so we know it should start ('t_start') toward the beginning of the snippet. Note that
    # 't_start' and 'call_dur' represent indices, not actual time (they are rounded below).
    t_start = pm.TruncatedNormal('t_start', mu=params.t_start_mean, tau=1.0/params.t_start_var,
                                 a=1,b=sig_T-2,
                        value=np.zeros(N_whales)+params.t_start_mean)
    call_dur = pm.TruncatedNormal('call_dur', mu=params.call_dur_mean, tau=1.0/params.call_dur_var,
                                  a=1,b=sig_T-t_start,
                         value=np.zeros(N_whales)+params.call_dur_mean)                    

    # Just hard-code this for now, later make it learnable
    sig_obs_var = 1

    # Prior parameters of C. Straight out of one of the pymc examples
    nu_0 = pm.Uniform('nu_0', 1., 3, value=1.5)
    phi_0 = pm.Lognormal('phi_0', mu=.4, tau=1, value=1)
    theta_0 = pm.Lognormal('theta_0', mu=.5, tau=1, value=1)        

    nu_1 = pm.Uniform('nu_1', 1., 3, value=1.5)
    phi_1 = pm.Lognormal('phi_1', mu=.4, tau=1, value=1)
    theta_1 = pm.Lognormal('theta_1', mu=.5, tau=1, value=1)

    # The covariance function for the no-whale cases
    @pm.deterministic
    def C_no(eval_fun = pmgp.matern.euclidean, diff_degree=nu_0, amp=phi_0, scale=theta_0):
        return pmgp.NearlyFullRankCovariance(eval_fun, diff_degree=diff_degree, amp=amp, scale=scale)    
    # Mean function -- prior mean for no-whale cases
    # mean zero is probably a good-enough guess for now
    @pm.deterministic
    def M_no(eval_fun = lambda x: 0 * x):
        return pmgp.Mean(eval_fun)

    # The GP sub-model(s) for the no-whale cases
    # I'm not really sure how to implement this.
    # I think all no-whale cases should share a common prior mean and covariance function,
    # but each individual instance (trial) should have a different underlying signal
    # (a draw from the prior mean), around which noise is added to get the observed data.
    # Do I need a separate sub-model (as I've coded here) for each no-whale trial to get this
    # behavior? I'd rather just tell a single sub-model to draw a new sample from the prior mean
    # for each new trial, but I'm not sure how.

    # use the container trick to hold all no-whale the sub-models
    sm_no = np.empty(sig_N, dtype=object) 
    for si in range(sig_N):
        sm_no[si] = pmgp.GPSubmodel('sm_no_%i' % si, M_no, C_no, fmesh_nowhale)


    # Cov function and prior mean for 'whale' cases
    @pm.deterministic
    def C_whale(eval_fun = pmgp.matern.euclidean, diff_degree=nu_1, amp=phi_1, scale=theta_1):
        return pmgp.NearlyFullRankCovariance(eval_fun, diff_degree=diff_degree, amp=amp, scale=scale)    

    @pm.deterministic
    def M_whale(eval_fun = lambda x: 0 * x):
        return pmgp.Mean(eval_fun)

    # GP submodel for 'whale' cases. Here we'll pretend that it is sufficient to have a single signal
    # for all whale calls around which we add noise to get the observed data. In other words,
    # a single draw from the prior mean is sufficient for all 'whale' trials, in contrast to
    # the no-whale trials above. Remember, though, that on 'whale' trials the call is embedded
    # in a longer signal, so it is surrounded by a 'no-whale' signal. This is 
    # instantiated in get_sig_means(), below.
    sm_whale = pmgp.GPSubmodel('sm_whale', M_whale, C_whale, fmesh_whale)    

    # Given the underlying signals from the 'whale' and 'no-whale' GPs, embed
    # a whale call on each 'whale' trial
    @pm.deterministic()
    def get_sig_means(wtf=wtf, sm_no=sm_no, sm_whale=sm_whale,t_start=t_start,call_dur=call_dur):        
        sig_means = np.zeros_like(sigs)
        w_ctr = 0
        for si in range(sig_N): # loop over trials
            #print si
            if wtf[si] == 1: # this is a 'whale' trial
                this_start = int( t_start[w_ctr] ) 
                this_dur = int( call_dur[w_ctr] ) 
                chunk0_t = range(this_start) # indices for the pre-call chunk of signal
                chunk1_t = range(this_start,this_dur) # indices for the call chunk
                chunk2_t = range(this_start+this_dur,sig_T) # indices for post-call chunk

                # build the signal, i.e., embed a call in the background ('no-whale') signal
                # ?? It seems that calling, e.g., sm_whale.f(x) returns 
                # values deterministically. That is what we want, given the code here,
                # but it seems inefficient to have all these separate no-whale submodels.
                # It would be better, it seems to me, if we could have a single no-whale 
                # submodel from which we draw a new realization for each trial. How?
                sig_means[si,chunk0_t] = sm_no[si].f(chunk0_t)
                sig_means[si,chunk1_t] = sm_whale.f(chunk1_t)
                sig_means[si,chunk2_t] = sm_no[si].f(chunk2_t)
                w_ctr += 1
            else: # this is a no-whale trial
                # Nothing to embed, just use the whole no-whale signal
                sig_means[si,:] = sm_no[si].f(range(sig_T))
        return sig_means

    # To get the observed signals we just add iid Gaussian noise to each datum, given the underlying
    # signal from the GP. Note, we always observe 'sigs'. When training we also observe 'wtf', so
    # we know whether or not there is a whale. When predicting we want to predict
    # whether or not there is a whale, given the 'sigs' and the model.
    signals = pm.Normal('signals',mu=get_sig_means,tau=1.0/sig_obs_var, value=sigs, observed=True)

    return locals()
```